# Display Screen When Clicked Image

Tags: flutter, dart

im learning flutter, how can i display a new screen when a image is pressed in Flutter?
this is my code:

```
 Column(
          children: [
            Stack(children: [
              Center(
                child: Image.network(
                  'https://exerciseright.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/image-from-rawpixel-id-2107431-jpeg-compressed.jpg',
                  width: 350,
                ),
              ),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 150, 0, 150)),
              const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Best Routines',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    height: 4,
                    fontSize: 40,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
//// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the image with a `GestureDetector` and navigate to the new screen with the `onTap` method like this:

```
       Column(
          children: [
            Stack(children: [
              Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    // * Navigate to the new screen
                  },
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://exerciseright.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/image-from-rawpixel-id-2107431-jpeg-compressed.jpg',
                    width: 350,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 150, 0, 150)),
              const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Best Routines',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    height: 4,
                    fontSize: 40,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
```